# Automatic UV scaling like in level editors? For white boxing game levels

Tags: uv

I want to design and white box my game levels in Blender, but I can't figure out how to automatically scale my UVs when scaling/extruding geometry.

I want the UVs to automatically adjust to cover a fixed distance regardless of the size of the geometry, like this:
[image: level editor]

I'm guessing it is kind of like triplanar mapping, except I need to actually adjust the UVs, and not just be a shader effect.

Is there anyway to do this, so I can make Blender easier to use when white boxing my game levels?

**EDIT**

The [Magic UV](https://github.com/nutti/Magic-UV) add-on works perfectly for my needs.